Is distributions defining necessary for a DAG to be a causal bayesian network?
First, let's define the following abbreviations: Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG), Bayesian Network (BN), Causal Bayesian Network (CBN), Conditional Probability Table (CPT), Conditional Probability Distribution (CPD).
For BN, I am merely certain that it contains a DAG, and this DAG is subject to certain constraints. The question now is whether a BN consists solely of a DAG. Is distributions defining necessary for a DAG to be a causal bayesian network?
As shown in the two images below, image 1 is from the book Probabilistic Graphical Models: Principles and Techniques, which explicitly states that a BN requires CPDs as components. Image 2 is from Causality: Models, Reasoning, and Inference, and in its description, the keywords CPDs/CPTs are not mentioned. Thus I am confused: Is BN just a DAG (a structure)? Which explaination to believe? If the answer varies depending on the context, then what are the different answers in different contexts?


Furthermore, let’s discuss CBN. We know that CBN also requires a DAG, but the question remains the same: Are distributions necessary for a CBN? As shown in the image 3, Pearl seems to suggest that a CBN is simply a DAG that is compatible with P_*. The definition of "compatible with" is shown below:
Definition 1.2.2 (Markov Compatibility)
If a probability function P admits the factorization of (1.33) relative to DAG G, we say that G represents P, that G and P are compatible, or that P is Markov relative to G.
Does the requirement for Markov Compatibility in a DAG imply that defining distributions is necessary? If not, how should "compatible with P_*" be understood?

Thus, I am very confused. The answers I observe online vary. The following content (image 4) is from the paper "Toward Practical Causal Epidemiology" (which is also the Google-recommended answer). I have seen similar questions on StackExchange, but the question (Does a Bayesian network include the CPTs?) is limited to CPT, which is typically used to describe the conditional probability distribution of discrete random variables, ignoring the existence of CPD and no references was given. The following was part of the question's answer, which was correct indeed but pitily not enough.
"If you take a Bayesian network structure and parameterize it, then it defines a probability distribution. However, before adding the parameterization, it only defines constraints on the distribution. And in general, a BN may include continuous variables - so there might be no CPTs at all!"

I sincerely request guidance from a distinguished expert in this field, to illuminate our path and allow us to catch a glimpse of the truth. Make us to know, and not to be led in ignorance. Yea, make us to know if Bayesian needs distributions defining. Amen!

“Let P be a joint probability distribution of the random variables in some set V, and G = (V, E) be a DAG. We call (G, P) a Bayesian network if (G, P) satisfies the Markov condition. ”
This is from Learning Bayesian Networks, which seems right. It means that joint probability distribution is necessary for a DAG to be a bayesian network.

I agree that the terminology can be somewhat imprecise, as terms like "causal graph", "directed acyclic graph (DAG)", "Bayesian Network (BN)", and "Causal Bayesian Network (CBN)" are often used interchangeably. This fuzzy language likely comes from their close theoretical connections within the framework of Structural Causal Models (SCM), as established by Judea Pearl.
To be more precise, a DAG is a mathematical structure that encodes relationships among certain entities. In the context of a BN, these entities are random variables, and the relationships correspond to the conditional independencies along with a particular factorization of the joint distribution. By definition, (plain vanilla) BNs always have a DAG structure. If a BN satisfies the local Markov property relative to the DAG, then all relevant conditional independencies can be inferred directly from the DAG. In this sense, the local Markov property conceptually "equates" the BN with its underlying DAG for the purpose of identifying conditional independencies.
A similar alignment occurs between BNs and CBNs. A CBN is a special form of a BN that satisfies some extra criteria: i) the Markov property, ii) consistency, and iii) invariance to irrelevant interventions. These properties enable CBNs to not only identify conditional independencies directly from the DAG but also to infer direct causal relationships. Thus, the CBN is effectively "equated" with its DAG when it comes to identifying direct causes.
In summary, while DAGs, BNs, and CBNs are distinct mathematical entities—with BNs and CBNs requiring probability distributions—their close interconnections and the properties that allow them to be equated for specific purposes often lead to fuzzy language.
